# Regular expressions with an alternative if the first one doesn't match

Tags: regex

I need to have a regular expression that takes a function signature as an input and returns the name of the function, i.e I may have the following input:

```
FUNCTION(A,B,C)
```

and after applying the following regular expression:

```
^(.*?)(?=\()
```

I correctly obtain the word "FUNCTION" as expected.

However, sometimes I can get the name of the function WITHOUT parentheses (and therefore without parameters), like this:

```
FUNCTION
```

In this case, the previous regex fails and doesn't take the name. Is there any way to define a regex that, in case it cannot find the first regular expression, try another one? (In this case would be taking the whole input.)

Answer (score 2):

From what I see, you want to match the first *n* characters other than `(`, `)` and space.

Thus, it is much more efficient to use

```
^[^()\s]+
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/gF9oJ9/2)

Comment: The number of steps to match my sample input is 4-5-2, and vks -  57-60-2 (see *regex debugger* on regex101.com).

Answer (score 1):

```
^(.*?)(?=\(|\s*$|\s)
```

This should do it for you.You need to use `|` or operator.

`\s*$` === stop if you have 0 or more spaces and then string ends

`\s` ==== stop at the first instance of space

Comment: Yeah it works, thank you! Could you "decipher" the meaning of the part you added to the regex? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @DavidJiménezMartínez added

Comment: This solution is too cumbersome. Whenever there is a way to avoid `.*?`, use an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

```
^([^)]+)\s*\(?
```

Could do what you want.

Explanation :

`([^(]+)` : one or more character that is not (

`\s*`  : maybe some blank spaces

`\(?` : optionnal parenthesis

Comment: Something is not right I think. After trying the regex, it take more than just the name. (Tried with several "FUNCTION and FUNCTION(a,b,c)" in notepad++. Yet the solution provided by @vks matches correctly.